# How can I see the list of customers I created in Intuit AggCat API?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

discoverAndAddAccounts will create customers and deleteCustomer will remove them.  As I was testing I created customers and now I don't have their IDs so I can't delete them.

I don't see a method for that on https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/index.php?title=0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0020_Aggregation_%26_Categorization_Apps/AggCat_API/0020_API_Documentation

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not an API to get this information. You will need to keep track of them.

Please submit a support ticket and we will have to get the information for you.

William

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using getCustomerAccounts.

[getCustomerAccounts](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/index.php?title=0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0020_Aggregation_&_Categorization_Apps/AggCat_API/0020_API_Documentation/0040getCustomerAccounts)